# Wavefunctions of quantum point contacts

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, semiconductor-physics, nanoscience

I have a question about the potential and wave functions of discrete energy levels of quantum point contacts. Assuming one has a rectengular potential well:
Can the potential of the QPC be assumed to be infinite or is it finite and the charge carriers also have a probability of being outside the potential well?
Is it also necessary for the wave functions to drop to zero at the edges so that the quantized conductance can be observed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the potential of the QPC be assumed to be infinite or is it finite and the charge carriers also have a probability of being outside the potential well?

Much depends here on the actual physical realization of the device in question; Just to name a few possibilities:

- QPCs formed using split-gate techniques (i.e., by applying potential to the gates on the top of a device containing two-dimensional electron gas, and thus confining it even more.)
- Epitaxially grown quantum wires - essentially heterostructures (like p-n jucntions), where the wires is formed by a different material embedded into a host material, although the two may be rather closed, e.g. in AlGaAs/GaAs heterostructures
- Chains of atoms with tunneling between them, connected to electrodes.

In the second case the potential barriers forming the wire are likely to be low and the wave function extends far away, whereas in the last case they can be treated as almost infinite confinement (or even described by a one-dimensional hopping Hamiltonian.)

The actual geometry of the structure can be also rather different. Technically, one should distinguish quantum point contacts (QPCs) from quantum wires.
A **QPC** can be simply an opening between two two- or three-dimensional electron gases, but with the transparency limited to a very narrow region (a few de Broglie wave lengths.) In other words, it can be thought of as a hole in an otherwise non-transparent screen. This is in fact the model that was considered in the [original paper by Sharvin](http://www.jetp.ras.ru/cgi-bin/e/index/e/21/3/p655?a=list).

**Quantum wires** also exhibit conductance quantization, but these literally contain extended one-dimensional regions, where the conductance quantization can be easily demonstrated as the cancellation between the group velocity of electrons and the density of states.

This distinction is often overlooked when looking at simple conductance quantization, but becomes crucial when taking about interactions - long wires are better described by the theories based on Luttinger liquid or even Wigner crystals, while Kondo-like physics description seems more appropriate for short QPCs. See, e.g., [*Wigner and Kondo physics in quantum point contacts revealed by scanning gate microscopy*](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms5290) and references therein.

> Is it also necessary for the wave functions to drop to zero at the edges so that the quantized conductance can be observed?

No: as we know from the quantum mechanics, quantized levels can be observed even for wave functions extending to infinity, as, e.g., in the harmonic oscillator. Thus, one of the models used for QPC is saddle-point potential (assuming for simplicity that the system is already confined in 2D):
$$
V(x,y)=-\frac{m\Omega_x^2x^2}{2}+\frac{m\Omega_y^2y^2}{2}
$$
Showing conductance quantization here requires dealing with parabolic cylinder functions for x-component of the wave function, but it is possible.